# Why $I^2$ a vector space where $I$ is the space of differentiable functions vanishing at a point $x$

Tags: manifolds, tangent-spaces

I am reading the following wikipedia article on tangent spaces, in particular, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_cotangent_spaces) subsection on the definition via the cotangent space. Here is a paraphrasing of the first two sentences of the first paragraph at the given link.

"Consider the ideal $I$ that consists of all smooth functions $f$ from the manifold $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at $x\in M$. Then $I$ and $I^2$ are real vector spaces."

I am bothered by the claim that $I^2$ is a real vector space. It is my understanding that $I$ is the set of all smooth functions from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at $x$ and that $I^2$ is the set of all functions that can be expressed as the product of two elements of $I$. (If I have gotten anything wrong so far please let me know)

It is not clear to me that $I^2$ is closed under vector sum, as this would require that for any functions $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ in $I$, there must exist functions $g_1,g_2$ such that $f_1f_2+f_3f_4 = g_1g_2$. It is not clear to me that this is the case.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually an abuse of notation when defining sets like $I^2$. In this case, $I^2$ is defined as the space of the functions that look like
$$
\sum_{i} f_ig_i
$$
where $f_i, g_i \in I$. This is now easily seen to be a real vector space.